# Obtener un dato de una consulta sql en Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, postgresql

Estos rescatando un id de una tabla para poder trabajarlo por separado, el problema que tengo es que al momento de obtenerlo la consulta sql me lo da como un array lo cual no he podido convertirlo a string.

Aqui el codigo:

```
        $idCliente=DB::select("SELECT id FROM clientes WHERE nit=$nit");

            echo $idCliente;
```

el array solo contendra un solo elemento, pero no e podido convertirlo a cadena a pesar que es un solo elemento.
esto me sale como error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero obtener ese "id" de la consulta como un string, pero no he podido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando el Query builder, la sintaxis correcta sería:

```
$idCliente = DB::table('clientes')
                 ->select('id')
                 ->where('nit', $nit)
                 ->first()
                 ->id;
```

Primero defines la tabla, luego seleccionas el campo que deseas, posteriormente agregas la condición, después le dices que quieres solo un registro con el método first() y por último obtienes la propiedad id, que equivale al campo que necesitas.

Por favor revisa la documentación para que aproveches las herramientas de Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses

Comment: Fenomenal, no sabia lo útil que podría a ver sido Query builder,Gracias!

Comment: si no te preocupes, solo que me salio un mensaje de stackoverflow diciendo que tenia que esperar como 6 minutos, pero lo hare. Gracias nuevamente